# postgresql add constraint Check on 3 columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `personnes`

```
jouer=# create table personnes (
g_name VARCHAR ( 50 ),
f_name VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE,
company BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false)
;
```

resulting in:

```
 Colonne |         Type          | Collationnement | NULL-able | Par défaut 
---------+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------+------------
 g_name  | character varying(50) |                 |           | 
 f_name  | character varying(50) |                 |           | 
 company | boolean               |                 | not null  | false
```

I want to add a constraint so that:

- if company is true, g_name and f_name must be null and
- if company is false, g_name and f_name are both required to be not
  null.

I have tried 2 things, but neither give the right result.

```
jouer=# ALTER TABLE personnes ADD CONSTRAINT personnes_company_check CHECK (
company is false
and g_name is not null
and f_name is not null)
;
ALTER TABLE
```

and

```
jouer=# ALTER TABLE personnes ADD CONSTRAINT personnes_company_check CHECK (
company is true 
and g_name is null
and f_name is null)
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's various ways to write this. A literal translation of your requirement would be a [conditional expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)

```
ALTER TABLE personnes ADD CONSTRAINT personnes_company_check CHECK (
  CASE WHEN company
    THEN g_name IS NULL     AND f_name IS NULL
    ELSE g_name IS NOT NULL AND f_name IS NOT NULL
  END
);
```

but I'd prefer

```
ALTER TABLE personnes ADD CONSTRAINT personnes_company_check CHECK (
  company = (g_name IS NULL) AND
  company = (f_name IS NULL)
);
```

which you could also split into two separate constraints.